# Rewrite is not working well

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wanna change this url: http://domain.nl/template/houses

To: http://domain.nl/houses

And houses is a dynamic value.

I have tried a few things, but nothing works. This is what i've tried:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/template/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
```

Can someone help me? Sorry for duplicated questions, but nothing is working well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I wanna change this url: http://domain.nl/template/houses`
>
> `To: http://domain.nl/houses`

I believe you have your rules in reverse. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/template/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ template/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! It still not working, but it's maybe a server problem! I'll check it soon. Thanks anyway. I think this was what i needed.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, it still not working well. I'm using MVC framework, so when u do this: www.site.nl/name is he searching for a controller called name. Can i fixed that?

Comment: @Bvweijen: I am on mobile at present. Please leave some details of the problem you're facing and I will attend it as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: @Bvweijen: I am back online. Please provide details of your problem, like which URL isn't working and what error you get. As per this rule `/name` will be internally rewritten to `/template/name` is that not you want?

Answer (score 1):

This may work better (tested on Debian/Apache2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?template/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! It still not working, but it's maybe a server problem! I'll check it soon. Thanks anyway. I think this was what i needed.

Comment: Hi @jacouh, it still not working well. I'm using MVC framework, so when u do this: www.site.nl/name is he searching for a controller called name. Can i fixed that?

Comment: You should read all details about MVC specification. How the controller is called? what the controller then call other php scripts?